# How to add a mapping to an already existing Index with elastic4s?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I would like to know if it's possible to add a mapping for a given type to an already existing index with the elastic4s API?

I've looked around and all the examples seem to create the mapping at index creation time, but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot change the properties for a type once you have created it. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings